# ¿Cómo actualizar valor de un campo en tabla donde no existan datos relacionados en otra tabla?

Tags: sql, sql-server, update

Necesito hacer un `update` a un campo en la tabla de clientes dónde ese cliente no tenga facturas en la tabla de facturas, el campo que las relaciona es el de `CodClie`, he intentado con un `inner join` pero no me da ningún resultado, como podría hacerlo correctamente?

Este es el Query de `UPDATE` con el que intente hacer la actualización del campo Activo

```
UPDATE SACLIE
SET Activo = '0'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT SACLIE.CodClie
FROM SACLIE 
INNER JOIN SAFACT ON SAFACT.CodClie <> SACLIE.CodClie
WHERE SAFACT.TipoFac IN ('A','F') AND
SAFACT.CodClie <> SACLIE.CodClie)
```

Comment: Podrias agregar la estructura de las tablas y el error que te tira?. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tienes la idea general correcta, pero la lógica está un poco mal.

Como regla general, en SQL Server por cuestiones de rendimiento, hay que incluir la tabla que vamos a actualizar en el `FROM` cuando se involucran otras tablas.

Después, hay que utilizar igualdades en las condiciones cuando involucren llaves primarias y foráneas, porque casi cualquier desigualdad será verdadera. La negación la obtienes gracias al `NOT EXISTS`.

Al final, la consulta quedaría así.

```
UPDATE C
SET Activo = '0'
FROM SACLIE AS C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT F.CodClie
                    FROM SAFACT AS F
                    WHERE F.CodClie = C.CodClie
                    AND   F.TipoFac IN ('A','F'));
```